# Protecting a file in an apk

Tags: android, encryption

I'm working to create a dictionary for android. I have a csv file containing all the data, which I worker for few months to complete.

The problem is anybody can explode the apk and extract the csv file. I wish secure the file. How can I protect a file inside the apk by not breaking the application?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 1):

You could save an encrypted version of the file, and decrypt it inside your application.

EDIT: for instance, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16912933/1367571) is a quick an simple solution for encrypting/decrypting data.

Comment: Yes, this may prevent casual ripoffs but ultimately becomes an arms race of obfuscation and discovery, because the algorithm/keys used to decrypt it are present in the app and available to extract, too.  The only way to truly protect it would be to keep it on a server and rate-limit queries, but that leads to poor usability.  Perhaps try to have the value somewhere other than the dataset?

Comment: True. However, unless we are talking about valuable data targeted by tens of crackers, a well-encrypted file should keep at bay at lease the majority of them.