# Hiding Files in sd-card in Android

Tags: android, file, security

i am creating an android app. i need to hide files in my sd card or put files in an folder n protect it using password only accessible  by my app. Any suggestion regarding this.

Comment: Can you use internal storage?

Answer (score 0):

There's basically 2 things you can do.

1. Use [internal storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal). This works great for most purposes, but might not work in every purpose. It is private by default.
2. If you have to use external for some reason, you want to encrypt the data. You either want to ask the user for a password, or create a device specific password for each app. Rather than duplicate work on this front, I'll point you to another question already asked on the subject, [Java File Encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16911632/java-file-encryption)

Comment: i want to store file in external storage . n user create its own password. i want the folder to be accessible only by my app.